# Use pandas groupby with networkx add_path

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, pandas-groupby

I want to add paths to a network in networkx from a pandas dataframe.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
                        file       node
0           1_final_position         5
1           1_final_position        12
2           1_final_position        15
3           1_final_position         2
4           2_final_position         3
5           2_final_position         7
6           2_final_position        16
7           2_final_position         8
8           3_final_position        11
```

I would like to add paths based on the 'file' column in the dataframe. So path 1 would be  `[5,12,15,2]`, path 2 would be `[3,7,16...]` etc.

I've already tried this

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_path(nodes=(data.groupby('file')['node']), attr=(data['file']))
```

but I get this error:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

So how do I use the `groupby()` function to add a new path? Or do I need to loop over something that splits the 'node' column based on the `file` column and then use this in add_path?

Comment: I am not very familiar with networkx, but where're your traj/centroid columns?

Comment: your error was most likely because you are trying to use mutable objects (e.g. dict, list, dataframe, series) as keys to query for something else which is mapped to this key. (i.e. the value in a key value pair.) Mutable objects can change without notice so it cannot be used as a key,which needs to stay constant over the course of its existence.

Comment: @stucash you're right, I could simply solve this problem like this:

grouped = data.groupby('file')['node'].apply(list)

for list in grouped:
    G.add_path(list)

Thanks for your help!